# How can Two particles in perpendicular S.H.M. interfere?

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, interference

While studying the simple harmonic motion of a particle, I came across this concept of the interference of two particles in S.H.M. Everything made sense until it was about two mutually perpendicular particles on the X and Y axis.

I don't understand how two particles performing their independent oscillations can affect a particle on the other axis (They do, take the Lissajous figures). I could be missing something fundamental, but this one has been plaguing me for so long. Please help.

Also, when I ask this question, I also wonder how two particles in S.H.M. of the same amplitude and frequency, but different phase angles, be at the same position at the same time for them to interact.

Well, this entire time, I am assuming that two particles must collide to interfere. Is this assumption correct? I am sorry for being so silly but I can't help it. I don't understand this one phenomenon.

Comment: This calculation might help, although it has 2 vibrations with same amplitude, frequency and phase, whereas in yours it has different phase. By analysing the equations used you should be able to work it out: ["Two mutually perpendicular simple harmonic vibrations have same amplitude, frequency and phase. When they superimpose the resultant form of vibration will be?"](https://learn.careers360.com/engineering/question-help-me-solve-this-two-mutually-perpendicular-simple-harmonic-vibrations-have-same-amplitude-frequency-and-phase-when-they-superimpose-the-resultant-form-of-vibration-will-be/)

Comment: Also try these links: @ https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/two-particles-executes-shm-along-the-same-line-at-the-same-frequency-they-move-in/    and  @ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fl4S600vJCY .

Comment: *I came across this concept of the interference of two particles in S.H.M.* Where?  This does not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand how two particles performing their independent oscillations can affect a particle on the other axis (They do, take the Lissajous figures).

No they don't. As you say, the oscillations are independent. The fact that the 2D trajectory $\big(x(t),y(t)\big) = \big(\sin(at+\delta),\sin(bt)\big)$ is generally complicated doesn't mean that the horizontal motion affects the vertical motion or vice-versa.

If you look at the "shadow" of the trajectory projected onto the $x$-axis, then the shadow will follow the simple harmonic trajectory $x(t)=\sin(at+\delta)$. If you look at the shadow projected onto the $y$-axis, it will follow the simple harmonic trajectory $y(t) = \sin(bt)$.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the response. I understand that these particles are in independent S.H.Ms across their axes, then why do we see such shapes as circles or ellipses when we observe these particles but not a simple plus sign, I could be missing something very fundamental but please help. When I look at the textbook solutions, they simply solve these two S.H.M. equations simultaneously to find the locus of the figure. I can't follow this step, pls help.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the interference of two particles.
What is described by the Lissajoux figures is a complex motion of a single particle. This motion can be described as the superposition of two simple harmonic motions along two perpendicular axes. Same as the projectile motion on a parabolic trajectory can be described as the superposition of two motions along the x and y axes.

Comment: Thank you for the response. But in the projectile, the ball actually follows a parabolic path and we break the motion into the x and y component for simplicity. But here if we have a laser attached to a particle oscillating on the x-axis and a similar arrangement for a particle oscillating on the y-axis, what we ultimately see is the formation of shapes such as circles and ellipses. Long story short, if my particles were at x=1 and y=1, why did I see the resulting figure passing through (1,1) when nothing actually is present on (1,1)?

Comment: @UpasnaSingh That's not what happens in a Lissajous figure. There aren't two independent particles which are oscillating - it's that the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of the single particle oscillate independently. If you have something else in mind, you should provide a source so we can see what you're talking about.

Comment: @UpasnaSingh I think you misunderstood the formation of Lissajous figures. Where did you see this thing, with a laser attached to two particles?

Comment: hi I could be mistaken, this is the exact video that I watched , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DObrU30VZBg&t=431s

Comment: Also, I am very new to this topic so, I could be misunderstanding the content of this video.

Comment: OK, interesting. Here the oscillating "thing" is the laser spot on the screen. You impose two independent oscillations on this spot by using two vibrating mirrors (attached to the tuning forks). Each vibrating mirror affects the spot on the screen but not each other.